# Java finding a file with recursion not looking in other subdirectories

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on a simple java program to recursively find files and print out the directory the file's located in. This is my current code:

```
// Library imports
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

// FindFile class
public class FindFile
{
    // Main method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Scanner object
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Directory
        File dir = new File(".");

        // Printing string to standard output
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of a file:");

        // Blank string variable
        String input = "";

        // Reading user input
        input = in.nextLine();

        // Calling findFile
        findFile(dir, input);

        // Closing scanner
        in.close();
    }

    // findFile method
    public static File findFile(File dir, String fname)
    {
        // root = dir (user input)
        File root = dir;

        // Array of files
        File[] list = root.listFiles();

        // if the array of files isn't null, proceed with the following operations
        if (list != null) 
        {
            for(File f: list) 
            {
                if (f.isDirectory()) 
                {
                    File path = f.getAbsoluteFile();
                    return findFile(path, fname);
                }
                if (f.getName().equals(fname)) 
                {
                    System.out.println(root.getPath());
                    return f;
                }

            }
            System.out.println(fname + " not found!");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am told when passing "." as the argument to the file class it will search the current directory where my file is located. However, it is only searching the bin folder which is an issue because I need to be able to search both src and bin (the whole project folder essentially). I cannot simply change the argument to the path to the project as my path is different then the paths the automated tests use (my class uses mimir). I'm confused on how to do this. I don't know if theres an error in my code, or if I'm not using the right convetion. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the absolute path to the project directory try this:

1. By using:

   ```
   System.getProperty("user.dir");
   ```
2. Get the current directory by using `getAbsolutePath()`:

   ```
   File currentDirFile = new File(".");
   String helper = currentDirFile.getAbsolutePath();
   String currentDir = helper.substring(0, helper.length() - 
                                      currentDirFile.getCanonicalPath().length());
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the java.nio.file library?  Files.walkFileTree recursively walks the file directory.  This recursively prints out all the files, followed by the directories of my c:\program files starting directory

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    printDirs(Paths.get("C:\\program files"));
}

public static void printDirs(Path start){
    try{
        Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                throws IOException
            {
                System.out.println("Filename: " + file.getFileName());
                System.out.println("Path: " + file.getParent());
                System.out.println();
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("Problem accessing file: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Excerpt of output:

```
Filename: History.txt
Path: C:\program files\7-Zip

Filename: af.txt
Path: C:\program files\7-Zip\Lang

Filename: an.txt
Path: C:\program files\7-Zip\Lang

Filename: ar.txt
Path: C:\program files\7-Zip\Lang

Filename: ast.txt
Path: C:\program files\7-Zip\Lang

Filename: az.txt
Path: C:\program files\7-Zip\Lang

Filename: ba.txt
Path: C:\program files\7-Zip\Lang
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and seems like the code do not check all directories.

If you change this line **return findFile(path, fname);** TO **findFile(path, fname);** your code will check all directories. but the output will be something like this:

App.java not found!
App.java not found!
App.java not found!
/FOLDER/THA/THAS/YOUR/FILE
App.java not found!
App.java not found!
App.java not found!

**You could try something like this as well**, that use **nio** and **java 8**.

```
        try {
            final String input = in.nextLine();
            URI uri = new URI("file:///".concat(dir.getAbsolutePath()));
            Path path = Files.walk(Paths.get(uri)).filter(i -> i.getFileName().toString().equals(input)).findFirst().orElse(null);
            if ( path == null ) {
                System.out.println( path );
                return;
            }
            System.out.println(  path.toFile().getAbsolutePath() );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```